# xslt: Remove one line comment including space

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform this

```
<appSettings>
  <!-- comment1 -->
  <add key="Value1" value="11" />

  <!-- comment2 -->
  <add key="Value2" value="22" />
</appSettings>
```

into this using xslt

```
<appSettings>
  <!-- comment1 -->
  <add key="Value1" value="11" />

  <add key="Value2" value="22" />
</appSettings>
```

This is the xslt I tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()[contains(., 'comment2')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But then I get

```
<appSettings>
  <!-- comment1 -->
  <add key="Value1" value="11" />

\r\n__  <- NewLine and Spaces I want to avoid
  <add key="Value2" value="22" />
</appSettings>
```

How can I remove the line having the comment node completely?

[XSLFiddle](http://xsltransform.net/ncntCS1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you could try removing the `indent="yes"` option from `xml:output` and then having a template to match, and ignore, any whitespace only node that immediately precedes the comment.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()[contains(., 'comment2')]" />
  <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]
                             [preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::comment()[contains(., 'comment2')]]]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tested at http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LV3

Comment: Great! From what I understand preceeding..[1] is a textnode having a comment as a child. Correct?. I also stripped it down to ´node()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][contains(., 'comment2')]]´

Comment: `node()` matches elements, comments, text nodes and processing instructions. If you did `preceding-sibling::comment()[1]` it will find the first comment that precedes the current text node, but it need not be the most immediately preceding sibling. So, the current expression is saying "For this text node, is the most immediate preceding sibling node a comment node that contains "comment2"

Comment: Thanks I will play around to get a stable solution. But it will take a while to use this intuitively

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

at the top level of your stylesheet.

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#strip

Comment: This also removes the newline between all other nodes.

Comment: You cannot have it both ways. If you want to preserve existing whitespace, then the whitespace surrounding the removed comment node will be preserved too. If you must, you might consider *adding* newlines where you want them. I am not sure it's worth the effort, though - why is this so important?

Comment: I agree it is not needed but I was wondering if XSLT is a complete language in the sense I can transform arbitrary XML documents into arbitrary target documents. This includes whitespaces. From what I understand now is that the model is restricted to pure data not formatting.

Comment: I wouldn't jump to such conclusion. It 's just more complicated than it's worth. You would have to match the text node(s) just before and/or after the comment and remove the orphaned newlines.